# Javascript cookie gets deleted when browser is closed

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am setting an expiration date and cookie using this:

```
var field = "Joe";
var expiration_date = new Date();
expiration_date.setFullYear(expiration_date.getFullYear() + 1);
document.cookie = "username="+field;+"path=/; expires=" + expiration_date.toUTCString();
```

When I try:

```
console.log(expiration_date)
```

I get this, which is right:

```
1 Sun Nov 16 2021 21:30:35 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

When I do

```
console.log(document.cookie)
```

I see the cookie. But when I close the browser and open again, and run the above command again, the cookie is not there. I've tried on Chrome and Edge.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to change the browser?

Comment: As mentioned in the question: I've tried on Chrome and Edge.

Comment: look closely at your code ... `document.cookie = "username="+field;+"path=/; expires=" + expiration_date.toUTCString();` ... that's `document.cookie = "username="+field;` one statement, followed by `+"path=/; expires=" + expiration_date.toUTCString();`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you just opened the html file on its own. Most browsers do not save cookies from the file, you need to upload it to a website. They store the cookie for just the session (This is the only problem I could think of). But if you are using cookies, you surely are accessing it from an actual link.

Comment: It's on a live site.

Comment: That's weird. Do you have any extension that blocks cookies? But you changed browers.

Comment: all browsers store cookies locally, they don't send the cookies to be stored on the server. Sure, cookies are sent as part of requests, but they certainly are stored in the browser

Answer (score -1):

> document.cookie = "username="+field;+"path=/; expires=" + expiration_date.toUTCString();

you append a semicolon after field which means cookie terminate there , parameter like expires and path don't applied for cookie, so delete it ";".
after semicolon put the expires and then put the path.

```
document.cookie = "username=" + field +"; expires="+expiration_date.toUTCString()+"; path=/";
```